# React based - make a draggable list item without any libraries

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, sorting, draggable

I have a to-do list and I want to make it **draggable** to be able to move list items and resort them if I drop them.
I want to do this without any package and library, just want to do it with **javascript** and **HTML**, and **CSS**.
I have a Todolist component and a Listitem component.

this is the part of my Todolist component that displays the render method:

```
  render() {
   const List = this.state.todolist.map((item) => {
     return (
       <Listitem 
         key={item.key}
         handleDrag={this.handleDragItem}
      >
    })
  }
        <div
          id="todoList"
          onDragOver={this.handleAllowDrop}
          onDrop={this.handleDropItem}
        >
          {List}
        </div>
```

and here is my drag functions :

```
  handleDragItem = (event) => {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
  };
  handleAllowDrop = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };
  handleDropItem = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  };
```

and here is my Listitem component:

```
class ListItem extends Component {
  render() {
    let isDraggable;
    }
    return (
      <div
        draggable={isDraggable}
        onDragStart={this.props.handleDrag}
        className="listItemContainer"
      >
        <img
          onMouseDown={() => isDraggable= true}
          onMouseUp={() => isDraggable= false}
          className="dragIcon"
          src={draggingIcon}
          alt="drag-icon"
        />
        <span>
          {this.props.content}
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have two problems, first one is that I can't reorder and resort the list when one row drags and drop to another part of the list.
The second one is that I can't drag my row with a specific part of the row like img tag

I actually want to permit the list items dragged just with the drag icon.

Comment: you are right dear @RandyCasburn
thanks for your attention